# Numba is 10x slower than python equivalent in task which it should be good at

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba

I have the following function:

```
def dewarp(image, destination_image, pixels, strength, zoom, pts, players):
    height = image.shape[0]
    width = image.shape[1]
    half_height = height / 2
    half_width = width / 2

    pts_transformed = np.empty((0, 2))
    players_transformed = np.empty((0, 2))

    correctionRadius = sqrt(width ** 2 + height ** 2) / strength

    for x_p, y_p in pixels:
        newX = x_p - half_width
        newY = y_p - half_height

        distance = sqrt(newX ** 2 + newY ** 2)
        r = distance / correctionRadius

        if r == 0:
            theta = 1
        else:
            theta = atan(r) / r

        sourceX = int(half_width + theta * newX * zoom)
        sourceY = int(half_height + theta * newY * zoom)

        if 0 < sourceX < width and 0 < sourceY < height:
            destination_image[y_p, x_p, :] = image[sourceY, sourceX, :]
            if (sourceX, sourceY) in pts:
                pts_transformed = np.vstack((pts_transformed, np.array([[x_p, y_p]])))
            if (sourceX, sourceY) in players:
                players_transformed = np.vstack((players_transformed, np.array([[x_p, y_p]])))

    return destination_image, pts_transformed, players_transformed
```

The arguments are:
image and destination image: both a 3840x800x3 numpy array
pixels are a list of pixel combinations, I've tried a double for loop too, but the result is the same
strength and zoom are both floats
pts and players are both python sets

The pure python version of this takes about 4 seconds, the numba version usually about 30 seconds. How is this possible?

I've used dewarp.inspect_types and numba appears to not be in object mode.

For convenience if you'd like to recreate the example, you can use this as image, destination image, pts and players and check for yourself:

```
pts = {(70, 667),
 (70, 668),
 (71, 667),
 (71, 668),
 (1169, 94),
 (1169, 95),
 (1170, 94),
 (1170, 95),
 (2699, 86),
 (2699, 87),
 (2700, 86),
 (2700, 87),
 (3794, 641),
 (3794, 642),
 (3795, 641),
 (3795, 642)}

players = {(1092, 257),
 (1092, 258),
 (1093, 257),
 (1093, 258),
 (1112, 252),
 (1112, 253),
 (1113, 252),
 (1113, 253),
 (1155, 167),
 (1155, 168),
 (1156, 167),
 (1156, 168),
 (1158, 357),
 (1158, 358),
 (1159, 357),
 (1159, 358),
 (1246, 171),
 (1246, 172),
 (1247, 171),
 (1247, 172),
 (1260, 257),
 (1260, 258),
 (1261, 257),
 (1261, 258),
 (1280, 273),
 (1280, 274),
 (1281, 273),
 (1281, 274),
 (1356, 410),
 (1356, 411),
 (1357, 410),
 (1357, 411),
 (1385, 158),
 (1385, 159),
 (1386, 158),
 (1386, 159),
 (1406, 199),
 (1406, 200),
 (1407, 199),
 (1407, 200),
 (1516, 481),
 (1516, 482),
 (1517, 481),
 (1517, 482),
 (1639, 297),
 (1639, 298),
 (1640, 297),
 (1640, 298),
 (1806, 148),
 (1806, 149),
 (1807, 148),
 (1807, 149),
 (1807, 192),
 (1807, 193),
 (1808, 192),
 (1808, 193),
 (1834, 285),
 (1834, 286),
 (1835, 285),
 (1835, 286),
 (1875, 199),
 (1875, 200),
 (1876, 199),
 (1876, 200),
 (1981, 206),
 (1981, 207),
 (1982, 206),
 (1982, 207),
 (1990, 326),
 (1990, 327),
 (1991, 326),
 (1991, 327),
 (2021, 355),
 (2021, 356),
 (2022, 355),
 (2022, 356),
 (2026, 271),
 (2026, 272),
 (2027, 271),
 (2027, 272)}
image = np.zeros((800, 3840, 3))    
destination_image = np.zeros((800, 3840, 3))
```

Am I missing something? Is this just something numba cannot do? Should I write it differently? Thanks!

The line profiler shows that a lot, but not the majority is being done by numpy. So there should be room for imporovement right?
[image: line profiler]

Comment: before using numba it might be a really good idea to delve into general optimization of code. This includes for example what Dunes said: Not repeating any operations like `vstack` which create new arrays each time. You will be a million times better off by preallocating an array of the required size and only filling it in the loop, if the loop is even required at all. (I guess it will work without any explicit loops at all. But you need to show the content of `pixels` to be sure about this.) And if you can't guess the size before looping just make a guess + security factor and slice afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you are using Numba, you should avoid incrementally growing an array in a loop, since that has very bad performance, you should instead preallocate an array and fill it one by one (since you may not know the exact size in advance, you can preallocate it with the largest possible, like `len(pixels)`, and slice out the unused space at the end). However, your code can just be vectorized in a more or less straightforward manner.

```
import numpy as np

def dewarp_vec(image, destination_image, pixels, strength, zoom, pts, players):
    height = image.shape[0]
    width = image.shape[1]
    half_height = height / 2
    half_width = width / 2

    correctionRadius = np.sqrt(width ** 2 + height ** 2) / strength

    x_p, y_p = np.asarray(pixels).T
    newX = x_p - half_width
    newY = y_p - half_height
    distance = np.sqrt(newX ** 2 + newY ** 2)
    r = distance / correctionRadius
    theta = np.arctan(r) / r
    theta[r == 0] = 1
    sourceX = (half_width + theta * newX * zoom).astype(np.int32)
    sourceY = (half_height + theta * newY * zoom).astype(np.int32)
    m1 = (0 < sourceX) & (sourceX < width) & (0 < sourceY) & (sourceY < height)
    x_p, y_p, sourceX, sourceY = x_p[m1], y_p[m1], sourceX[m1], sourceY[m1]
    destination_image[y_p, x_p, :] = image[sourceY, sourceX, :]
    source_flat = sourceY * width + sourceX
    pts_x, pts_y = np.asarray(list(pts)).T
    pts_flat = pts_y * width + pts_x
    players_x, players_y = np.asarray(list(players)).T
    players_flat = players_y * width + players_x
    m_pts = np.isin(source_flat, pts_flat)
    m_players = np.isin(source_flat, players_flat)
    pts_transformed = np.stack([x_p[m_pts], y_p[m_pts]], axis=1)
    players_transformed = np.stack([x_p[m_players], y_p[m_players]], axis=1)
    return destination_image, pts_transformed, players_transformed
```

The part that is more different to your code is how to check if `(sourceX, sourceY)` is in `pts` and `players`. For that I computed the "flat" pixel indices and used [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) instead (you may add `assume_unique=True` if you know that there will be no repeated pairs of coordinates in each input).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why this algorithm would see any significant benefit from using numba. All the heaving lifting appears to be in the image copying and `np.vstack` sections. That's all in numpy, so numba won't help there. The way you iteratively uses `vstack` also has terrible performance. You'd do better to build a list of sub-arrays and the stack them together all in one go at the end.

As to what the problem is, what does 
`dewarp.inspect_types()` output? It should show you where numba needs to interface with Python. If this is done anywhere in the loop then performance will suffer if your program is multi-threaded.

Comment: Ok so I switched to lists but even so, looking at the line profiler (I'll edit the OP) it's pretty clear only 15% is done by numpy. All the rest is simply because python loops are very slow. In fact, I made a rust version of this and it can run the same kind of code in 400ms. Problem is that rust-python communication has a lot of overhead so the whole thing still takes 1.6 seconds... I was hoping numba would have the performance of rust without the overhead.

Comment: Hi, would you share the rust-python version, if possible?